# TFS API TestManagementService always returns null

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to get test plans by using TFS API.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://xxxxxxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));

var service = (ITestManagementService)tfs.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
```

The variable "service" always returns null.

Do you have any idea, why?

Comment: tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore)) returns the store object but ItestManagementService returns null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're linking against different versions of reference assemblies, mixing different versions of Visual Studio assemblies? Example:

- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` v11.0 (VS 2012)
- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client` v12.0 (VS 2013)

I had the same problem of `GetService<ITestManagementService>()` always returning null, even when `GetService<VersionControlServer>()` would return good (non-null) value.

The solution posted in [MSDN - VersionControlServer always returns null](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0e965405-b98f-4394-a2a6-f3f3ea377e0c/versioncontrolserver-always-returns-null) worked for me: I had references to some v11.0 (VS2012) and v12.0 (VS2013) assemblies.  Changing all references to v11.0 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try to make sure you that you are authenticated to the Team Project Collection before calling the Get Service command.  This code snippet works correctly for me:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();

ITestManagementService service = tpc.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
```